# Error with x-axis labels when plotting multi-index dataframe using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a timeseries dataframe and I've calculated a season column from the datetime column. I've then indexed the dataframe by 'Season' and 'Year' and want to plot the result. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), columns =list ('A'))
df['date'] = dates

def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return 'spring'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return 'summer'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return 'autumn'
    else:
       return 'winter'

df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df.loc[df['date'].dt.month == 12, 'Year'] += 1
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)

df.head()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x_compat=True,ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this gives me the error when plotting the x axis labels:

```
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 225, in _from_ordinalf
dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix)

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

I want to see only the year as the x-axis label, not the year and the season.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm doing wrong but I can't figure out what...

**EDIT:**

Changing the df.plot function slightly plots the dates a bit better, but still plots months, I'd prefer to have only the year, but this is slightly better than before.

new code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), columns =list ('A'))
df['date'] = dates

def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return 'spring'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return 'summer'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return 'autumn'
    else:
        return 'winter'

df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df.loc[df['date'].dt.month == 12, 'Year'] += 1
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)

df.head()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='date', y = 'A', x_compat=True,ax=ax)
```

Comment: its unclear to me exactly what you're trying to do here. Your code runs without errors for me (but does not plot any xticks). If I remove the three `ax.xaxis...` lines, the code still runs, and I get xticks labelled as `(2007,winter), (2007, summer)` etc.

Comment: Please always include the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: @cel cheers, edited to include full error

Comment: @tom sorry, I'm trying to only show the year as the label, not the season and the year - Q edited to show this

Comment: I think you did it yourself already - when I take your second code block and add the three `ax.xaxis.set_....` lines from the previous code to it, I get what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the marriage between `pandas` and `matplotlib` time locator/formatter is never a happy one.  The most consistent way is to have the datetime data in a `numpy` `array` of `datetime`, and have that plotted directly in `matplotlib`.  `pandas` does provided a nice `.to_pydatetime()` method:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(dates.to_pydatetime(), df.A)
years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
```

[image]